# How to make two shapes in two different tables overlap

Tags: html, html-email

I have been able to create the two rounded rectangle shapes and I want the second shape beneath the first shape to overlap with the first shape.
Well if the two shapes can be in different tables, I think that would be great and that would mean overlapping two tables so as to make the shapes overlap. Or well whatever is best, I think you know better.

The second shape would be the only shape containing write up

The first picture is showing the two shapes. And the second picture is showing how I want the shapes to overlap.
Thank you so much [this is the first image] [this is what I would like it to be like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1rdJ.jpg)

Comment: Are you able to post your code so far? And/or host the images so we can test it?

Comment: Ok Nathan, I will in a short while thank you